# Issues with Kattis "0-1 Sequences" Solution

Tags: java

Since last night I have been working very hard trying to write a solution to the problem "0-1 Sequences" (https://open.kattis.com/problems/sequences) on Kattis. At this point, I am at my wits end. I keep getting the wrong answer on the third test case, and I've tried everything I can possibly think of to fix my code. I'm fairly certain that the formula I am using to compute the result is correct, and I haven't been able to find an example where it gives the wrong answer. I suspect the issue is something to do with how I am calculating the modulus, but I've written and rewritten the relevant parts of the code and I am still failing each time. Below is my code (sorry in advance, I've been working like a madman with not much regard for writing "nice" code).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class oneZeroSequences {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    //leading zero's have no effect on the number of inversions, 
    //and we therefore get rid of them all right off the bat.
    while(s.charAt(0)=='0'){
        s=s.substring(1);

        if(s.length()==0){
            System.out.println(0);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(findSum(s));
    System.exit(0);
    
}

public static long findSum(String s) { 
    int m=1000000007;
    long res = 0;
    //if passed an empty string, the sum of inversions is obviously 0
    if(s.length()==0){
        return 0;
    }
    while(s.charAt(0)=='0'){
        s=s.substring(1);

        if(s.length()==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if the first character of the string is a question mark, we handle the case
    //where that question mark is 1 first, and then remove the question mark since
    //leading 0's have no effect on inversions.
    while(s.charAt(0)=='?'){
        res+=findSum("1"+s.substring(1))%m;
        s=s.substring(1);
        if(s.length()==0){
            return res%m;
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> qArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int start=0;
    int found;
    //here we construct an array of the indices of question marks in the string
    while(true){
        found=s.indexOf('?', start);
        if(found==-1){
            break;
        }
        qArray.add(found);
        start=found+1;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> zeroArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    start=0;
    found=0;
    //here we construct an array of the indices of 0's in the string
    while(true){
        found=s.indexOf('0', start);
        if(found==-1){
            break;
        }
        zeroArray.add(found);
        start=found+1;
    }
    long k = qArray.size();
    long a = zeroArray.size();
    long zeroSum = sumArrayList(zeroArray);
    long qSum = sumArrayList(qArray);
    Double dres = 0.0;
    //the formula for sum of inversions is as follows:
    //2^k*(zeroSum) + 2^(k-1)*(qSum) - (a^2-a)*2^(k-1) - (2a-1)*2^(k-2) - (k^2+k)*2^(k-3)
    //the following lines of code apply this formula, taking the modulus at each step.
    if(k>=3){
        res += (expBySquaringMod(2, k)*(zeroSum%m))%m;
        //res=(res%m+m)%m;
        res +=((expBySquaringMod(2, k-1))*(qSum%m))%m;
        //res=(res%m+m)%m;
        res -= ((((((a%m)*(a%m))%m)-a%m)%m)*expBySquaringMod(2,k-1))%m;
        //res=(res%m+m)%m;
        res -= (((((2*a-1)%m)*(k%m))%m)*expBySquaringMod(2,k-2))%m;
        //res=(res%m+m)%m;
        res-= (((((k%m)*(k%m))%m+k%m)%m)*expBySquaringMod(2, k-3))%m;
        //res=(res%m+m)%m;
        return res%m;
    }
    //the expBySquaringMod function will give incorrect 
    //results for negative exponents, hence the following code.
    dres += ((Math.pow(2,k))*(zeroSum%m))%m;
    dres=(dres%m+m)%m;
    dres +=((Math.pow(2,k-1))*(qSum%m))%m;
    dres=(dres%m+m)%m;
    dres -= (((((a%m)*(a%m))%m-a%m)%m)*(Math.pow(2,k-1)))%m;
    dres=(dres%m+m)%m;
    dres -=((((2*a-1)%m*(k%m)%m)*(Math.pow(2,k-2))))%m;
    dres=(dres%m+m)%m;
    dres-=((((k%m)*(k%m)%m+k%m))%m*(Math.pow(2,k-3)))%m;
    dres=(dres%m+m)%m;
    res+=dres.intValue()%m;
    return res%m;

}
public static int sumArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int res = 0;
    for(int d : list) {
        res+=d;
    }
    return res;
}
//this function was written to deal with the massive powers of two required for the solution
public static long expBySquaringMod(int base, long exp) {
    int m=1000000007;
    long res=1;
    if(exp%2==0) {
        for(int i=0; i<exp/2;i++) {
            res=(res*base*base)%m;
        }
    } else{
        res=base;
        for(int i=0; i<exp/2;i++) {
            res=(res*base*base)%m;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. This problem has been causing me a lot of distress.

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to [over-emphasize your distress](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) because it's irrelevant; better would be to describe your algorithm and rationale step-by-step, and show all the attempts you made to fix it, concretely (in code/logic). I have no idea what rationale led you to lines like `(((((a%m)*(a%m))%m-a%m)%m)*(Math.pow(2,k-1)))%m;`, for example. What have you done to test it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for over emphasizing my distress. I was going crazy working on my code, but I've calmed down now. For the line you mentioned, I am essentially just trying to take the modulus at every single step of the computation. The specifics of the computation come from the formula I put in comments. I am not sure how to upload images, but if you tell me I can upload pictures of my derivation of the formula. In terms of testing, I have tried every small test case I could come up with (by hand), and they all gave correct results. I also tested my expBySquaringMod function for powers of 2 up to 500000

Comment: Thanks -- I'd [edit] that into the post.